# Django template browse a table with variable

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a query result on my views and i drop to my template, on my template i want to display values of my table, so i use 
`{{myTable.0}}` and `{{myTable.1}}` 
and i have the result of my query, but i want to display this values with a variable like `{{myTable.x}} where x =0` to use in a loop for.

But it doesn't work, so if you have any solution.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, don't worry for your english, most people on SO aren't native english speaker. I suggest you take a look to our Help section : http://stackoverflow.com/help. You should usually include the code that you have tried your question. Use the edit link-button to add more information into your post. Oh, and it is not necessary to welcome people, say thanks and add your name as a signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `myTable` is a list an you want to iterate through this list.  If so then you can use the [`{% for %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for) template tag:

```
{% for val in myTable %}
    {{ val }}
{% endfor %}
```